# Remove apps from Samsung Knox

Tags: applications, samsung, samsung-knox

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge 32GB. Recently I found out that out of the 32GB, at least 8GB is being used by apps inside Samsung Knox. Not Knox itself, but apps inside it.

I'd like to keep Knox for its features if my phone gets stolen, but I won't actively be using the apps within.

How can I delete apps like WhatsApp from Knox?

Comment: When an app is added to Knox and/or "Secure Folder", it's actually a copy of the app.  You can safely uninstall an app from knox and the copy of the app that lives outside of knox should still be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, WhatsApp is a system app in the main system and not in Knox. However, when you allow it to be copied to Knox, it will be a system app also in Knox.

When I tried to remove it from Knox, it removed itself from the main system also and defaulted to the preinstalled on the main and on the Knox.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I ended up calling samsung and they disabled Knox for me. Still stuck with a nearly full phone but at least it's slightly less.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open **Knox**
2. Go to **MyKnox Settings**
3. Scroll down to **Application manager**
4. Touch the app you want to uninstall
5. Tap on Uninstall

Note: System apps can't be uninstalled, but you can disable them.

---

[image]

WhatsApp can be uninstalled

[image]

MS Word can't be uninstalled

Comment: I only have `disable` and `force stop`

Comment: Those are for system apps I guess. Third party apps should be removed

Comment: I doubt WhatsApp is a system app.

Comment: No, WhatsApp ain't a system app. Please provide screenshoots of every steps

Comment: https://goo.gl/photos/TmG7YShhKjTxFyiY6

Comment: I don't speak the language displayed, can you upload in English please?

Comment: Left is "disable" right is "Force close"

Comment: Check my update. It is possible to uninstall WhatsApp and all user apps. Only system apps are not uninstalled but can be disabled.

Comment: WhatsApp is a system app now? GG Samsung

Answer (score 0):

For uninstalling apps in My Knox, you can go to My Knox settings and uninstall from the application manager.

---

I prefer using the original Knox pre-installed on our phones. It is more secure than "My Knox" from Play Store. Both are by Samsung, but with pre-installed Knox, you cannot use third-party apps which makes it more secure; with the latter one, other apps installed inside your Knox container can still access your files in your Knox container.

Still, the choice is up to you... (I am a Samsung Note user)

Comment: My phone installed the app by itself.

Comment: + I don't have "knox", I only have "My knox"

Comment: You need to uninstall your my knox to see the original knox.. & if u want to use it... you need to format your device once..

Comment: When I got the phone it asked me to use knox & I hit yes, so it's there, but it got thatapp, idk

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Android debugger even if you think you couldn't. No root required.

1. Unlock developer mode on your phone

   (i) Settings > About your phone > About your Software > Build number - tap it 7 times
2. Allow USB debug on the phone

   {} Developer mode > Debug > USB Debug (toggle)
3. Install "App Inspector" from Google Play to get package names for undesirable apps (Touch name with icon -> Package name)
4. Connect your phone to PC in "only charge" mode, allow debug
5. Install Android Debug Bridge

   For Linux OS, this is most likely `sudo apt-get install adb` , there are Windows packages as well. You also could connect Android to Android instead of PC and use the ADB OTG Android app from Google Play on an auxiliary device (Android Debug Bridge On The Go)
6. **Figure out user ID for Knox folder**

   ```
   admin@admin:~(10/18/21 13:07:24)$ adb shell
   1|star2lte:/ $ pm list users                                                                                                                                                                                      
   Users:
       UserInfo{0:Взрывоопасный Поцык:13} running
       UserInfo{150:Secure Folder:50020030} running
   ```

   `--user 0` is a default user, and `pm list users` allows you to find out Knox user number. Probably you should keep Knox folder unlocked.
7. Slaughter the bloatware

   ```
   star2lte:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.google.android.apps.tachyon                                                                                                                                           
   Success
   star2lte:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.samsung.android.bixby.agent.dummy                                                                                                                                     
   Success
   star2lte:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.android.chrome                                                                                                                                                        
   Success
   star2lte:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.samsung.clipboardsaveservice                                                                                                                                          
   Success
   star2lte:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.microsoft.office.excel                                                                                                                                              
   Success
   star2lte:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.facebook.services                                                                                                                                                   
   Success
   star2lte:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.facebook.system                                                                                                                                                       
   Success
   star2lte:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.facebook.appmanager                                                                                                                                                   
   Success
   star2lte:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.microsoft.office.word                                                                                                                                                 
   Success
   star2lte:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.microsoft.office.powerpoint                                                                                                                                           
   Success
   star2lte:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.samsung.android.bixby.service                                                                                                                                         
   Success
   star2lte:/ $ pm uninstall -k --user 150 com.samsung.android.kidsinstaller                                                                                                                                       
   Success
   ```

   Just don't cut anything sufficient

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Knox
2. Go to Settings
3. Go to Applications
4. Uninstall the app like any other
5. It will unistall only on Knox